# Questions about lowpass filters using 'butter' function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, filter, lowpass-filter

I am trying to design a lowpass filter in Matlab:

```
fc = 100;           % Cutoff frequency
fs = 4020;          % Sampling frequency
w_norm = 2*fc/fs;
filter_order = 1;
[num,denom] = butter(filter_order,w_norm)
sys = tf(num, denom)
[z,p,k] = zpkdata(sys)
```

Matlab gives me a pole at:

```
s = 0.8541
```

My questions are:

1. Where does this number come from? Shouldn't the pole be at w = 2*pi*fc = 628 rad/s (normalised to 1 if divided by wc)?
2. Shouldn't it be negative since butterworth LP filter poles are in the left half plane?
3. Why does Matlab also give me a zero at -1?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `butter` produces a *discrete-time* filter design. Therefore the transfer function is defined in terms of *z* (z-transform), not *s* (Laplace transform).

A discrete-time Butterworth filter of order *n* has an *n*-order zero at *z*=-1 and *n* poles within the unit circle. This is in accordance with your results. (In contrast, a continuous-time Butterworth filter would have an *n*-order zero at infinity and *n* poles in the left-hand unit semicircle).